# Ping between two different VMs on two different computers

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ping

I have two physical computers (windows 8 each of them) connected in a lan network. In both computers I have installed Oracle virtual box with windows server 2008. I want to ping from one Virtual Machine to the other one located in the other computer. How can I do it? For some reason I have the same IP on both virtual machines.

Comment: Change the IP addresses of the 2 VMs - maybe make them static.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have got the same MAC (hardware manufacturer's unique code) on your network interfaces in your two VMs so they are indistinguishable. You can check like this, and make a new random MAC address by clicking the green icon:

[image]

Comment: How are you getting on with this? Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

The VMs are likely on their own private networks behind software routers run by the VM program. Therefore, they are not visible to each other. This is the "NAT" (Network Address Translation") mode.

It's exactly as if two computers are behind two different DSL netboxes in two different homes. You cannot ping one from the other. You can only ping the netbox routers if you know their IP address.

To be able to ping between the two VMs, they need to take ownership of the host network card. This is called "Bridged Networking" in VirtualBox. Your host will be unable to use this network address as long as the guest VM is running.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the virtual computers in the same lan network as the physical computers are!